# Monorepo with design system in it?

Tags: directory-structure, monorepo

I am thinking about switching to monorepo.

Without monorepo the flow is like this:

```
Make changes in DS -> Pull Request to DS repo -> Build and publish to npm -> Create PR for each app with updating DS version -> Wait for approvals and builds
```

Even though this is kinda automated process (in our case), it is still very time consuming and if you forgot something, you will have to make all this again no matter how big is the actual change. Not to mention that there may be problems if someone update DS version before you fix breaking changes in apps.

I think that monorepo could solve this problem. The process will be optimizied and code delivery will be syncronized between all apps with structure like this:

```
monorepo
    /frontend-app-1
    /frontend-app-2
    /frontend-app-3
    /design-system
```

Design system contains all the common components that are used in other apps and other stuff.

So, is there a good practice how to do that or maybe certain tool/framework? I can see a bunch of problems with this approach already (i.e. building DS every time someone commits to any of projects), but I think this could be a good trade off comparing to current structure.

Comment: I currently have this setup in place and the main problem is DS team can't move forward until all frontend apps are sync'ed. Slow process.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco you mean you have monorepo and it is slow? I don't think it could be slower than polyrepo, but I haven't work in a company with more than one frontend team so it's hard for me to tell

Comment: It has its pros and cons. But when you have 20 frontends and you have a 10 mins change, but you can't merge until all 20 teams have checked the change won't break their thing (or even works, fix something on their end), you have a bottleneck.